# soapUI Maven integration error

Tags: maven, soapui, maven-plugin

I am getting error while running soapUI test from Maven.

> [INFO] --- soapui-pro-maven-plugin:4.6.1:test (default) @
>   HelloWorld.application

---

> Downloading:
>   http://www.soapui.org/repository/maven2/com/smartbear/soapui/soapui/4.6.1/soapui-4.6.1.jar
>
> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   com.smartbear.soapui:soapui-pro-maven-plugin:4.6.1:test (default) on
>   project HelloWorld.application: Execution default of goal
>   com.smartbear.soapui:soapui-pro-maven-plugin:4.6.1:test failed: Plugin
>   com.smartbear.soapui:soapui-pro-maven-plugin:4.6.1 or one of its
>   dependencies could not be resolved: Could not transfer artifact
>   com.smartbear.soapui:soapui:jar:4.6.1 from/to
>   SmartBearPluginRepository (http://www.soapui.org/repository/maven2/):
>
> GET request of: com/smartbear/soapui/soapui/4.6.1/soapui-4.6.1.jar
>   from SmartBearPluginRepository failed: Premature end of Content-Length
>   delimited message body (expected: 10092383; received: 7941773 -> [Help
>   1]

It seems there is some issue in soapui-4.6.1.jar. It is not getting download successfully. I tried downloading the jar file from browser but it was unsuccessful .

Comment: Could you post your pom.xml? Also you can try to remove $USER_HOME/.m2/repository/com/smartbear directory and try again.

Comment: Also,  It may be due to the server. I tried downloading from browser and even that failed at %70. You may try to download from browser, when it is successful you can update your local repository manually.

Comment: Seems like a network problem on your end? Try a different version to prove the point.

Answer (score 1):

It seems it was a network issue. Maven downloaded the file when I connected to internet using different service provider.